# Betti numbers of non-projective compact algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cohomology

Are there examples of complex smooth compact algebraic varieties (necessarily non-projective) with vanishing second Betti number?

If not, are there such examples whose Betti numbers do not satisfy the hard Lefschetz inequalities?

UPDATE: As follows from the comments below, the second Betti number never vanishes. The second question is still open. Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to have non-vanishing second Betti number (https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/complex-manifolds-which-are-not-algebraic/).

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread the question. Comment deleted.

Comment: For every scheme, every point has an open affine neighborhood.  The scheme is smooth if and only if the open affine can be chosen to have an etale morphism to affine space.  If the scheme has positive dimension, the inverse image of a line and a transverse hyperplane give a curve and a transverse hypersurface in the open affine.  Their closures in the smooth proper scheme give a closed curve and a closed hypersurface that intersect (dimensionally) transversally.  Thus, the Poincare duals of their cycle classes have positive intersection number.  So the second Betti number is always positive.